# How to execute a shell script after oracle started successfully

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to execute a shell script with non-root user while Linux system booting and oracle has been started successfully.

I tried to execute this shell in rc.local. But I found oracle start-up procedure took too much time. So when shell tried to connect to Oracle, it return failed.

On the user`s Linux server, it took several minutes to get Oracle running. I am not clear what technology they use. I found when Oracle didn`t startup finished, I can login Linux server through ssh.

In my opinion, Linux boot sequence should like following.

```
/etc/rc.d/rc.sysinit 
/etc/rc.d/rc $RUNLEVEL 
/etc/rc.d/rc.local 
/bin/login
```

But If I add line to check if Oracle is running in rc.local, user cannot login Linux server for several minutes. I think it is improper.

Is there a better solution to solve this problem?

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: I edited my question. I think  it is improper to do that. Is there any other way?

Comment: You could edit your script to parse oracles logs and only continue after the "Oracle started successfully" message.

Comment: Should I put this script in crotab?

Comment: this can be useful [oracle running process](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4718/how-check-that-the-oracle-database-is-up)

Comment: @Wendy You can either put it in crontab with `@restart` or add it to the default runlevel.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of this solutions and configure it to "wait" for oracle listen port.

https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it

Or

https://github.com/Eficode/wait-for

Comment: Thanks, I will check it.